# Handle state of Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I make the following this example [Tabs The Fragment way](http://thepseudocoder.wordpress.com/2011/10/04/android-tabs-the-fragment-way/)

I am saving the state of each `Fragment` using the `onSaveInstance` and the `onActivityCreate`

Lets Say I have 4 Tabs Each one associated with a `Fragment` ,

The Problem : 
IF i am in `Fragment` `A` and rotate the device ,saving state works fine ,
IF i am in `Fragment` `A` and rotate the device then move to `Fragment` `B` and rotate the device , Then returns to `Fragment` `A` the `Bundle` pass to `Fragment` `A` does not contains what `Fragment` `A` store in the `onSaveInstance`
 any body know why thats happened ???